# Open URL coming from Server in Webview

Tags: objective-c, ipad, webview

```
NSURL *homeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self URLEncodeString:URL]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:homeURL];

    //Set our self as the webview delegate (so methods below will be called)
    [myWebView setDelegate:self];

    //Start loading the webview's request
    [myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

in my iPad App i am using Webview (works perfectly fine), to open URL's comes from Server.
in one of my URL i am getting issue URL is as below:

www.google.com

if above URL i put on net it just open with https prefix....my URL can be of any kind...and depend of user input....

is there any generic way to open above URL....

Answer (score 0):

You might have to implement NSURLConnectionDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace 

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```